# How to sort over TimeUUID field in Solr?

Tags: sorting, solr, cassandra, datastax

Accordingly to [Mapping Solr types](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchSolrType.html) article UUIDField type can be used to represent Cassandra's TimeUUID fields. It works fine until I try to sort over that field in Solr. Seems that Solr sorts such fields as ordinary UUID. Am I right? How to sort over TimeUUID columns in Solr in that case?

Comment: It seems Solr don't support TimeUUID's so it just can't sort over it in time manner.